# about null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Hi
I have written such this code but it will return this exception .and I do not know why please help me thanks.

```
         private void Scan(DoublyLinkedList dList) { // T(n) = O(n)
    DNode p1 = dList.getFirst();


    while (p1!=null) {


        DNode p2 = p1.next;
         System.out.println(p1.getElement().toString()+"lol");
        if (p2.next!=null) {

         DNode p3 = p2.next;

            if(p3.getElement()!=null){

                boolean b = Determinate.isPointRightSide(p1.getElement(), p2.getElement(),p3.getElement());

                if (b == true) {
                    p1 = p1.next;
                } else {
                    p1.next = p3;
                    p3.prev = p1;
                    dList.remove(p2);
                    p1 = p1.prev;
                }


            }
            else break;


    }else break;}

}

    public static double determinate(Object get, Object get0, Object get1) {

    double data[][] = new double[3][2];

    data[0][0] = ((Point) get).getX();
    data[0][1] = ((Point) get).getY();
    data[1][0] = ((Point) get0).getX();
    data[1][1] = ((Point) get0).getY();
    **data[2][0] = ((Point) get1).getX();**
    data[2][1] = ((Point) get1).getY();


    return ((data[0][0] * (data[1][1] - data[2][1])) - (data[1][0] * (data[0][1] - data[2][1])) + (data[2][0] * (data[0][1] - data[1][1])));
}
```

exception:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ConvexHull.Determinate.determinate(Determinate.java:55)
        at ConvexHull.Determinate.isPointRightSide(Determinate.java:15)
        at ConvexHull.GrahamVersion.Scan(GrahamVersion.java:104)
        at ConvexHull.GrahamVersion.grahamScan(GrahamVersion.java:83)
        at ConvexHull.GrahamVersion.<init>(GrahamVersion.java:25)
        at UI.MainFrame.grahamButtonActionPerformed(MainFrame.java:221)
```

this will show that "p3" is null! but I have check "p3" why it returns "null" again?
I use **strong** for showing those lines that throws exception.

EDIT: Ihave edited my post but it will throw this exception for "p1"

Comment: I swear I just commented on a question similar to this one. Have you made sure to check if your `get` objects are not `null`?

Comment: get object for p3 is null!I do not know why ? I have checked it before with  !p3.equals(null)

Comment: I used p3!=null but still throws nullpointerexception.

Comment: Check whether `p3.getElement()` (not p3) is null since that's what is initializing `get1`.

Comment: I have checked that if (p3!=null) do not get determinate but it gets????

Comment: @ Adrian 1 I have use the way what you said ,it doesn't return nullpointerexception but its running time doesn't stop and will print one point a lot  of times.!!!!

Comment: if p3 = null then you don't do `p1 = p1.next`  which means you'll just have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

One thing that looks wrong is:

```
if (!p3.equals(null))
```

This will generally always be true (if `p3 != null`) or throw a NullPointerException (if `p3 == null`)

The correct way to test whether p3 is not null is:

```
if (p3 != null)
```

Although that may not be why you're getting your NullPointerException

If the NullPointerException occurs on the line you highlight, it must be because get1 is null.  This is passed in as `p3.getElement()`, so find out whether that could be null.

In theory, if `data[2]` was null then `data[2][0]` would throw a NullPointerException but since you initialize `data` then that won't be the problem in this case.

Also, is there some reason that your parameters for determinate() are `Object` instead of `Point`? If this is your actual code and not some simplified test-case, then the parameters should all be `Point` since that's what they must be.

**Edit:**
I see you've changed your original code to add some of the suggestions on this page.

But I still see some problems:

```
while (p1!=null) {
    DNode p2 = p1.next;

    if (p2.next!=null) {
//      ^^^^^^^ If p2 is null, then this will throw NullPointerException

     DNode p3 = p2.next;

     if(p3.getElement()!=null){
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   If p3 is null, then this will throw NullPointerException


         boolean b = Determinate.isPointRightSide(p1.getElement(), p2.getElement(),p3.getElement());
//                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ if one of these returns null then isPointRightSide() will throw a NullPointerException
```

Comment: Yep. You have to write it as "if (p3 != null)".

Comment: also my element in each node is an object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you got the wrong line, because this:

```
!p3.equals(null)
```

will not work - *that* line (or those involving `p1` or `p2`) is throwing the Exception. You cannot invoke *any* method on a `null`, including `equals()`. Use this instead for all your `null` checks:

```
p3 != null
```

Comment: also my element in each node is an object.

Comment: @user472221: your current code only checks p3.getElement() for null but not p3