# Condition in while loop doesn't work?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, while-loop

```
private void Scan(DoublyLinkedList dList) { // T(n) = O(n)
    DNode p1 = dList.getFirst();

    while (p1 != null) {
        DNode p2 = p1.next;
        System.out.println(p1.getElement().toString()); // <--- Here it throws NullPointerException.

        if (p2.next != null) {
            DNode p3 = p2.next;

            if (p3.getElement() != null) {
                boolean b = Determinate.isPointRightSide(p1.getElement(), p2.getElement(),p3.getElement());

                if (b == true) {
                    p1 = p1.next;
                } else {
                    p1.next = p3;
                    p3.prev = p1;
                    dList.remove(p2);
                    p1 = p1.prev;
                }
            } else break;
        }else break;
    }
}
```

the exception:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
X :8.0  Y: 9.0angle0.0lol
        at ConvexHull.GrahamVersion.Scan(GrahamVersion.java:102)
        at ConvexHull.GrahamVersion.grahamScan(GrahamVersion.java:83)
        at ConvexHull.GrahamVersion.<init>(GrahamVersion.java:25)
```

It throws `NullPointerException` on `System.out.println(p1.getElement().toString());`. It means that it doesn't pay attention to the condition of while loop?

Comment: In general you don't need to do do a `toString()` call on an object when you pass it into the function `println()` of a `PrintWriter` (such as `System.out`). The function will implicitly convert the object into a `String` by itself.

Comment: By [`String#valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Object%29), actually, which does implicit null pointer checking.

Comment: Looks pretty similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289981/about-null-pointer-exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p1` is not `null`, but `p1.getElement()` returned `null`.

Remove the `toString()` call. You don't need it there in sysout. It will then just print `null` as "null".

Comment: OK I want to handle that if there is no element in the p1 ,do not go to the while loop,I should use p1.getElement() !=null ?

Comment: Try it or just ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the `while` loop *does* work. The `NullPointerException` is thrown on `p1.getElement()`, which is `null` and therefore cannot be dereferenced. If `p1` were `null`, the line above it (`p2 = p1.next`) would fail.